# I'd like to test my app under simulated IO load - how can I do that?

Tags: linux

I want to simulate a server busy and then do other experiment in the busy server.
   Is there any Linux tool that can do the read and write with a specific rate in order to simulate the server busy (if using the dd and fio tools, they'll make the server too busy to do other thing). Thank you ：-）

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: @RobertColumbia If you want to apply the rules literally, then that's true. But the question could be changed to only "I'd like to test my app under simulated IO load - how can I do that?", which I'd say falls under "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: @RobertColumbia yes ,  maybe my real question is ""I'd like to test my app under simulated IO load - how can I do that?", I didn't make it clear. There is one answer that recommand the cgroup tool , it's a good idea ..  Thank you :-)

Comment: @CaiY could you edit it?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I have edited the title... ：-）

Comment: @CaiY - just to note [fio has several rate options](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-rate) (such as `rate` and `rate_iops `) which can control its maximum throughput and can stop it going flat out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the usual tools like `dd` as long as you can add [`throttle`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/throttle) to the pipe.

Keep in mind that you need to ensure the buffers in the reader (that's specific to each command) are not too large, otherwise, you could read a few megabytes into memory at once, and then throttle the memory reads, which is not what you want.

Alternatively you can use any command that you put into its own `cgroup`. Cgroups can have the io bandwidth limited system-wide. You can read more  [in this post](https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/)